# Does the Dodge Specialization add to the total for Dodge?

Tags: skills, shadowrun-sr5, dodge

If you have the gymnastics skill, which applies to dodge when you take a -5 initiative penalty (SR5 p.168), does the dodge specialization (comes preloaded as option in the chummer character creation program) add its +2 dice?

This section, from p.191 appears to do it,

> DODGE Any character, armed or unarmed, looking for a quick, short-term
>   boost to his melee defense can use a Dodge Interrupt Action against an
>   attack at any point in a Combat Turn, so long as the character is not
>   surprised (see Surprise, p. 192). A Dodge action allows the character
>   to roll Reaction + Intuition + Gymnastics [Physical] as his Defense
>   test. Note that since a skill is introduced to the Defense Test, a
>   limit is introduced as well. This boost only deducts 5 from his
>   Initiative

But this section from 168 doesn't say one way or the other,

> DODGE (–5 INITIATIVE SCORE) A character may choose to use her own
>   skill to dodge incoming attacks as an Interrupt Action (see Defending
>   in Combat, p. 188). By decreasing her Initiative Score, the defending
>   character can add her Gymnastics skill to the defense test. This is a
>   one-time add, unlike going on Full Defense (below) which lasts for an
>   entire Combat Turn.

Answer (score 2):

### No, it doesn't.

Dodge is not a valid specialization for gymnastics (page 133):

> Specializations: Balance, Climbing, Dance, Leaping,
>   Parkour, Rolling

*Parrying* on the other hand, since it uses a specific weapon from a group of weapons, uses the specialization bonus from the armed skill being used (blades, clubs, etc). *Blocking* is similar, but that is specifically called out as a specialization of Unarmed Combat.

Back in 4th edition, *Dodge* a specific skill, which you could specialize on melee or ranged combat. But that was replaced by gymnastics on 5th edition.

Comment: I have not been able to find what "Rolling" is. Any search for the word, in any combination with related words, just return results about rolling dice.